# windows: XP -> current: how to tell if in CONSOLE or RDP session?

Tags: c#, windows, session

I have a messy collection of Windows platforms in various labs. Everything from XP to the latest.  I have a simple C#/.NET app that runs at user login and logout.  I need to differentiate between true Console logins and RDP sessions.  I am using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId
```

to get a `sessionId` but I don't see anything that says "you are on the Console" or "you are in an RDP session".  Is there such a thing?

Comment: It looks like you have to compare the session id to a value in the registry to be sure... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380798(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For my needs it turns out that the windows environment variable `%sessionname%` holds the info I am looking for.  In my C# code I can say:

```
string sessionName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SESSIONNAME")
                     ?? "CONSOLE";
```

`%sessionname%` seems to hold either the string "console" or "rdp-(something)#(number)", ex "rdt-tcp#1234".  I don't know the whole range of possible values but it looks like it will work for my needs.

Comment: +1, I didn't know that. :-)  One caveat for other readers: this determines whether the current logon session was on the local physical console *when the user first logged on* rather than whether the user is *currently* on the local physical console.  For a logon script, this is presumably exactly what you want, but it may not be suitable for some other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which session ID (if any) is currently attached to the physical console by calling the [WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383835(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the "Minimum supported client" level is 
Windows Vista.  I am hoping for a solution that goes back to XP.  I may have to cobble something together but I'm hoping not.

Comment: Vista is shown as the minimum supported client for *all* API functions (well, depending on how recently the documentation was updated) simply because it is the minimum supported version of Windows.  To find out whether a function is in XP, you'll have to either try it and see or use an archiving service like the Wayback Machine.  In this case, a [copy of the page from 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120104040018/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383835(v=vs.85).aspx) shows that this particular function was indeed available in XP.

Comment: Turns out it maybe easier than all this.  Notbeing a windows person I was not aware until yesterday afternoon that there is an environment variable called `%sessionname%` that is either set to "console" or "rdp-<something>#<number>", ex. "rdp-tcp#1234".  This is sufficient for my needs I think and it is easy to access.  Cheers